# Setting element data-icon with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following button element in my HTML

```
<button id="play-pause" aria-hidden="true"></button>
```

On the jQuery ready event, I run the following code:

```
$('#play-pause').attr('data-icon', '&#xe00a;')
```

That turns the HTML element into this

```
<button id="play-pause" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe00a;"></button>
```

Which renders like this in the browser (Chrome stable):

[image: play pause button]

However, if I delete the JavaScript code, manually change the HTML to the following (it's the same thing as the JS waas doing) and refresh the page:

```
<button id="play-pause" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe00a;"></button>
```

then it renders like this:

[image: play pause button rendered properly]

What's the difference?

I suspect it's irrelevant but here's the CSS:

```
/* Use the following CSS code if you want to use data attributes for inserting your icons */
[data-icon]:before {
    font-family: '45sound';
    content: attr(data-icon);
    speak: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: are you using jquery UI buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Unicode value:

```
$('#play-pause').attr('data-icon', '\uE00A');
```